# I used FLAG_IMMUTABLE in my pending intent but again I'm getting the below error

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.?
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle intent in backgroud.
here is the code which need to be in your class extendend By FirebaseMessageService

```
@Override
public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    RemoteMessage remoteMessage = new RemoteMessage(intent.getExtras());
    onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
}
```